# Обобщения: склонение, число

Tags: склонение, число

Озадачился вопросом числа (в некоторых случаях склонения) для обобщающих фраз (выделенно в примере). Просьба дать пояснения или ссылку на правило.

*Для нагревателей **должно быть предусмотрено** местное управление и аварийные термореле.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что такое "склонение для обобщающих фраз" я не очень понимаю, а вот про число - пожалуйста:

> Форма сказуемого при однородных подлежащих зависит от ряда условий: от
>   положения сказуемого по отношению к однородным подлежащим (препозиция
>   или постпозиция), от значения союзов, соединяющих подлежащие
>   (соединительные, разделительные, противительные или сопоставительные),
>   от лексического значения существительного в роли подлежащего
>   (отвлеченные понятия или названия лиц; вещественно близкие или далекие
>   и т.д.)...

В Вашем примере сказуемое в препозиции + соединительный союз = ед. ч.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Валгина Н. С.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-030.htm)

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Очень доходчиво.

Comment: Если ответ действительно помог, нужно кликнуть по звездочке снизу-слева от ответа, чтоб было мне ЩАСТЕ! )))